# On the proper use of `\tl_rescan`

Tags: expl3, catcodes

Looking at the code below, what would the setup  in 6. have to be to return F? Also, why does 2. return F in other words how are `\group_begin:` and `\c_group_begin_token` different?

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item \tl_if_head_is_N_type:nTF{{foo}}{T}{F} % 1. F
\item \tl_if_head_eq_catcode:nNTF{{foo}}\group_begin:{T}{F} % 2. F
\item \tl_if_head_eq_catcode:nNTF{{foo}}\c_group_begin_token{T}{F} % 3. T
\item \token_if_group_begin:NTF\c_group_begin_token{T}{F} % 4. T
\item \tl_if_head_is_N_type:nTF{[foo]}{T}{F} % 5. T
\item \tl_if_head_is_N_type:nTF % 6. T
{\tl_rescan:nn
  {\char_set_catcode_group_begin:N [
      \char_set_catcode_group_end:N ]}
  {[foo]}}{T}{F}
\end{enumerate}
```

UPDATE:

What was lost on me the first time around is that using predicates such as `\tl_if_head_eq_catcode:nNTF` as second argument to`\tl_rescan` is a bad idea to detect any change to catcode specified in the setup as they are affected by the change themselves. That said, perhaps this new MWE explains better what I was trying to lead to.
Also, [I'm now clear on`\group_begin:` vs `\c_group_begin_token`].

```
\char91 % [
\char93 % ]

\cctab_const:Nn \c__erw_setup_cctab
{
  \cctab_select:N \c_code_cctab
  \char_set_catcode:nn  {91}{1}
  \char_set_catcode:nn  {93}{2}
}

\tl_rescan:nn{\c__erw_setup_cctab}
{\tl_if_head_eq_catcode:nNTF {{foo}}
\c_group_begin_token{T}{F}} % T

\exp_args:Nnx
\tl_rescan:nn{\c__erw_setup_cctab}
{\tl_if_head_eq_catcode:nNTF {[foo]}
\c_group_begin_token{T}{F}} % F
```

PS: feel free to delete the question if it's still not clear.

Answer (score 3):

TeX has two ways we can make a group: using `\begingroup`/`\endgroup` and using `{`/`}`. The latter can be achieved using a pair of tokens `\let` to `{`/`}`. In `expl3` terms, `\begingroup` is `\group_begin:` and `{` is `\c_group_begin_token`. These are distinct ideas so come out differently when tested.

When you do `\tl_if_head_is_N_type:nTF { \tl_rescan:nn ...`, the argument is *not* expanded: you are asking if `\tl_rescan:nn` itself is `N`-type. It is, so the test is true: it does not matter what the *output* of the rescanning would be.

Comment: But if I expand with `\exp_args:Nf` the argument of `\tl_if_head_is_N_type:nTF` I get the same result.

Comment: @Erwann I'm really not sure what you mean - can you edit the question?